# Copy constructor confusion

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Could anyone explain me the reason why is in this code defined `MyClass ( const MyClass & src ) { m_X = src . m_X; }` ? Without this line of code it works fine as well and gives the same output which is `32` in this case. What's the difference between having it in and not? I read that copy constructor is made automatically but when you have defined pointer in the class you should define it but i don't get why in this case.

Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass ( int x ) : m_X ( new int ( x ) ) {}
    MyClass ( const MyClass &src ) 
    {
        m_X = src.m_X; 
    }

    void  print ( void ) const 
    { 
        cout << *m_X; 
    }

private:
    int * m_X;
};


int main ( void )
{
    MyClass a ( 32 ), c = a;
    c.print ();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the same output is you are doing a shallow copy just like the compiler would do.  It is not enough just to copy a pointer.  You need to create a new pointer and then set its value to be a copy of what you are copying from.  A proper constructor would look like

```
MyClass ( const MyClass & src ) : m_X(new int(*src.m_X) {}
```

Now the copy has its own independent pointer that has the same value.

Also note that you need a destructor to delete the memory and a proper copy assignment operator as the default copy assignment operator will do the same thing as the default copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The default copy constructor as well as your copy constructor does a member wise copy (or shallow copy).  In this case you have a pointer which value is the address of where the data is located.  This address what is copied.

As noted in other posts you will need to manage pointers a little better.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the compiler generted one (and yours) is that it copies the pointer. You now have two pointers `c.m_x` and `a.m_x` both pointing at the same heap allocated object. Who owns it? What happens if you delete a, it should delete the memory it allocated (you incorrectly dont do this) , but c is still poining at it.

For this reason there is `std::shared_ptr`. It is designed for this case, it does the `Right Thing By Magic`

Replace `int * m_X` by `std::shared_ptr<int> m_X`